# PWA keeps being delisted as "Soft 404"

Tags: google-search-console, canonical-url, google-index, soft-404

Our main root domain for our PWA is here:
https://editor.construct.net

There are many versions of the product, all accessible in sub folders, EG:
https://editor.construct.net/r150/
https://editor.construct.net/r122/
https://editor.construct.net/r90/

The main editor page (and some previous versions) keep being de-listed as a "Soft 404".  This removes the root domain from search results completely (and site:editor.construct.net) results.

All old versions point their canonical URL to the main root domain.

I am 99.999% sure the URL's don't respond with a 404 (all content is static, behind Cloudflare and we receive no user reports of difficulties accessing the PWA), which leads me to believe Google is delisting for thin content.

We have a  tag on the editor page that has links and a little bit of content with the goal to pass link juice to our main website.  For technical reasons, we cannot have HTML content outside the  tag.

Does anyone know what we could do to stop Google delisting our PWA as a soft 404?

Comment: Have you tested having Google render the page using the "Inspect URL" tool in Google Search Console?   A "soft 404" can be caused by no text at the point that Google renders the page.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller here's the inspection result: https://i.imgur.com/G9YjYiC.jpg

Comment: No, I mean you need to "View crawled page" and look at the screenshot.  You might need to start a live test to get that.  Does it have any words on it?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller ah right you are, this is what is shown: https://i.imgur.com/G9s4rbz.png  

It appears to be running some of the load scripts but gets stuck here as incompatible with the crawler Chrome version.

Perhaps if we detect it's a Google crawler, and if so display content in that dialogue could that help?

Comment: That would be [cloaking](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66355?hl=en) so don't do that.  [Google just announced](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2019/05/the-new-evergreen-googlebot.html) they are upgrading Googlebot's Chrome version and are planning to keep it up to date with the latest going forward.  This may be a problem that goes away for you soon.